# C# List embedded files inside a PDF file and get a file stream to one of the embedded files

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I can create a PDF with embedded files using LaTeX for example:

```
\usepackage{embedfile}

\embedfile{abc.data}
\embedfile{def.data}
```

Using the Acrobat Reader I'm able to extract again the two data files.

But how can I do that from C#?

- How can I list the files which are embedded inside a PDF, similiar to a directory list?
- How can I get a file stream (readonly) to one of the embedded files inside a PDF?

Comment: What PDF library is in use?

Comment: @Fildor I'm thinking about using iTextSharp-LGPL, see https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL. Other suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions would be OT, I just wanted to know because answers may depend on used library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [iTextSharp-LGPL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL) PDF library I was able to solve it.

**List embedded file names**

```
public static string[] ListEmbeddedFileNames(string pdfFileName)
{
    string[] fileNames = new string[0];
    var reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfFileName);
    if (reader != null)
    {
        var root = reader.Catalog;
        if (root != null)
        {
            var names = root.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.NAMES);
            if (names != null)
            {
                var embeddedFiles = names.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
                if (embeddedFiles != null)
                {
                    var namesArray = embeddedFiles.GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.NAMES);
                    if (namesArray != null)
                    {
                        int n = namesArray.Size / 2; // I don't understand why I have to divide by 2
                        fileNames = new string[n];
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) fileNames[i] = namesArray[2 * i].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    return fileNames;
}
```

**Get embedded file stream**

```
public static Stream GetEmbeddedFileStream(string pdfFileName, string embeddedFileName)
{
    byte[] data = GetEmbeddedFileData(pdfFileName, embeddedFileName);
    if (data == null)
        return null;
    else
        return new MemoryStream(data);
}
```

and

```
public static byte[] GetEmbeddedFileData(string pdfFileName, string embeddedFileName)
{
    byte[] attachedFileBytes = null;
    var reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(pdfFileName);
    if (reader != null)
    {
        var root = reader.Catalog;
        if (root != null)
        {
            var names = root.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.NAMES);
            if (names != null)
            {
                var embeddedFiles = names.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.EMBEDDEDFILES);
                if (embeddedFiles != null)
                {
                    var namesArray = embeddedFiles.GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.NAMES);
                    if (namesArray != null)
                    {
                        int n = namesArray.Size;
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        {
                            i++;
                            var fileArray = namesArray.GetAsDict(i);
                            var file = fileArray.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.EF);
                            foreach (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName key in file.Keys)
                            {
                                string attachedFileName = fileArray.GetAsString(key).ToString();
                                if (attachedFileName == embeddedFileName)
                                {
                                    var stream = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream)iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(file.GetAsIndirectObject(key));
                                    attachedFileBytes = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (attachedFileBytes != null) break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    return attachedFileBytes;
}
```

I've checked my solution by computing MD5 checksums over the embedded files.